# Merging MultiLineStrings

Tags: openlayers-3

I have few OL3 MultiLineString objects like

```
Object { type: "MultiLineString", coordinates: Array[2] }
Object { type: "MultiLineString", coordinates: Array[3] }
Object { type: "MultiLineString", coordinates: Array[4] }
Object { type: "MultiLineString", coordinates: Array[3] }
```

Now I want to merge all of them in a new big MultiLineString ( like PostGIS `ST_Union` function ). Is there some way to do this using OL3 or I must deal with JS arrays?

Comment: What type of Object is MultiLineString? Is it `JSONObject` or a `ol.geom.MultiLineString`

Comment: I think it is a `ol.geom.Geometry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you look at the library [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts)

Personnaly, I use this library to make an union on two geometry.

```
var parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();

var a = parser.read(first_OlFeature.getGeometry());
var b = parser.read(second_OlFeature.getGeometry());

var unionGeometry = a.union(b);

var featureFromUnion = new ol.Feature().setGeometry(parser.write(unionGeometry));
```

Answer (score 0):

Until better solution:

```
var newMultiline = {};
newMultiline.type = 'MultiLineString';
var newCoordinates = [];


for(x=0; x < routeData.length; x++ ) {

    var geom = routeData[x].geometry;
    for (z=0; z<geom.coordinates.length; z++   ) {
        newCoordinates.push( geom.coordinates[z] )
    }

}
newMultiline.coordinates = newCoordinates;
```